# Can I use what I wrote on the shell (bash, cmd, irb, etc) in a script automatically?

Tags: bash, shell, cmd, irb

The general idea is pretty simple, I want to make a script for a certain task, I do it in the shell (any shell), and then I want to **copy the commands I have used**.

If I copy all the stuff in the window, then I have a lot of stuff to **delete** and to **correct**. (*and is not easy to copy from shell*)

Resume: I want to take all the things I wrote...

***Is there an easy way to do this easy task?***

---

Update: Partial solution

In **bash**, the solution is pretty simple, there is a **history** command, and there are ports of the idea:

**IRB**: [Tweaking IRB](http://blog.nicksieger.com/articles/2006/04/23/tweaking-irb)

**Cmd**: Use PowerShell -> **Get-History** (*or use cygwin*)

---

Another Update:
I found that **doskey** have a parameter history to do this:
**cmd**: Doskey /history >> history.cmd

Comment: Short question: What exactly should the line »Cmd: Use PowerShell -> Get-History (or use cygwin)« mean? PowerShell isn't cmd and doesn't have access to its history anyway. Cygwin likewise. I think you're confusing some things here.

Comment: The meaning is: If you want to have history in windows you have to use "power shell", there you have the Get-History cmdlet that do it.
(Or use cygwin (so you can use bash's history command))

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can use:

```
history -w filename.sh
```

This will save your command history to filename.sh.  You may need to edit that to keep just the lines at the end that are part of your command sequence.

NOTE:  This is a bash command and will not work with all shells.

Comment: +1, it won't work in *any* shell, but I doubt there's a general solution to the problem.

Comment: You can also use 'fc -l' (optionally with a range of command numbers) in both bash and ksh, which widens the scope slightly.

Comment: This page have a port of the idea to IRB:
http://blog.nicksieger.com/articles/2006/04/23/tweaking-irb

Answer (score 1):

**script** may help here.  Typing **script** will throw you into a new shell and save 
all input and output to a file called **typescript**.  When you're done with your interaction,
exit the shell.  The file **typescript** is then amenable to grep'ing.  For example, you might
grep for your prompt and save the output to the file.  If you're a clumsy typist like me, then you may need to do some cleanup work to remove backspaces.  There used to be a program that did thisbut I don't seem to find it right now.  Here is one I found on the
'net: http://www.cat.pdx.edu/tutors/files/fixts.cpp

This approach is especially useful if you want to track and post on the web an entire interactive session.

Comment: Thanks for that answer, it sound interesting and usefull, but not to  write the script actuallly (because you have to grep the file, with *history* is more simple...)